# How to create LDAP bind account in Centos/RedHat that allows me to search by ldapbind@server.com

Tags: openldap, ldap, slapd

I am creating an LDAP directory and searching by the full DN shows the proper results.

```
$ ldapsearch -x -D "cn=ldapbind,dc=server,dc=com" -w bind
```

I want / **need** to be able to search using the email address as in:

```
$ ldapsearch -x -D ldapbind@server.com -w bind
ldap_bind: Invalid DN syntax (34)
    additional info: invalid DN
```

We have an Active Directory that allows that kind of search but I don't know what configuration changes do I need in order to have that in LDAP.

I am not attaching my slapd.conf because I want someone to show me the right configuration to do this, and mine is quite minimal.